# Best STL data structure to find unordered elements

Tags: c++, data-structures, hashtable

I'm currently trying to implement a hash table in C++ for a homework...

I've chosen to use internal linking as a solution for collisions in the table...

and I'm looking for a good STL container that will find a specific entry in an unordered set of data.

I can't use an stl container that is based on trees (set, map, trees, etc...)

Right now I'm using a vector, is it a good choice? The search time will be linear, right? Can it be better?

Comment: Vector's OK, not necessarily optimal. Remove-from-middle isn't efficient, so if your buckets are allowed to get big you might compare it with `list` and/or `deque`. If your buckets aren't allowed to get big, `vector` may over-allocate. All three have linear search. The obvious structure that can beat linear lookup time is another hashtable (or the same table again), as in double hashing. Without an order there's nothing in the standard libraries: all they do is things with orders, and pure sequences.

Comment: `deque` may be better than `vector`, because it never has to reallocate and move everything. Access is slightly slower, push_back is potentially a lot faster, depending how expensive the elements are to copy. `list` typically does more memory allocation than either, and may be slower for that reason.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you're saying  `I assume the buckets can get big...`, it's better to use `std::list`. Searching is linear in both cases, but adding elements is constant in `std::list`.

`I guess they're all the same, since data isn't ordered` - No, they are not. If they were, there would be just one container. Each container has it's own advantages and disadvantages, different containers are used for different situations.

A little information about vector:

- `std::vector` has **capacity**, that's why it has `capacity()` and `size()` methods. They're both different. So, suppose the capacity is 4 and you have 2 elements, then size will be 2. So, adding another element will increment the size (will be 3) and it's all very fast.
- But what happens when you have to add 5+ elements and the capacity is 4? **Completely new** memory is allocated, **all** old elements are **copied** in the new memory, **all** old elements are **destroyed** (their destructors are called, if user-defined types). Then the old memory has to be **freed**. These are expensive operations if you think that adding/removing elements will be more often.
  You can avoid this, using `std::vector::reserve` method to reserve some memory in advance and not reallocate new memory all the time and copy everything over and over again. But this is useful when you know the approximate size of these vectors. I suppose you don't in your situation( reserving much memory is't a good solution, too - you should not waste memory *just like that* ) So, again, I'd prefer std::list.

Or double hash.

Anyway, this allocating of new memory and copying of objects will not happen that often, as `std::vector` is "clever" and when allocate new space, it doesn't increase the capacity with only 1 element or something. I think it doubles it, but I'm not that sure about that. Argh, I don't know how exactly this is called in English.. Probably something like "accumulative time/memory" or "accumulative complexity" :? Don't know :/

**NOTE:**  Whatever you choose, I'd suggest you to pay your attention at the hash-function. It's the most important here. A hash container should NOT have too many elements with the same hash. So, my advice is to search for a good hash-function and then this will not matter that much.

Hope that helped (:

---

EDIT: I'd recommend you this article - [comparing `std::vector` and `std::deque`](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/stl/vector_vs_deque.aspx) - it's perfect - compares memory usage (allocating, deallocating, growing), CPU usage, etc. I'd recommend the whole [**site**](http://www.codeproject.com) for such articles - there aren't many, but are really well written.

Comment: When I was mentioning that they were pretty much the same, I was talking about the speed of search (...since the data is unordered)

Comment: But I think I'll be using a dequeue or list for that matter, thanks for all the explanations. :)

Comment: @Pacane - sorry for misunderstanding you about "pretty much the same". I'm glad that I helped (:

Comment: vector doubling its capacity (or whatever the implementers felt like) leads to amortized constant complexity, meaning that in average it's constant.

Comment: @Matthieu - Riiiiiight, that's what I was looking for - "amortized constant complexity", not "accumulative xxx", thanks man (:

Comment: nice explanation & useful link... helped me too. :)

Answer (score 0):

`std::tr1::unordered_set` could be what you need.

Comment: Implementing a hash table using a hash table is pretty much defeating the whole point...